# Theorem 4.4, Apostol Mathematical Analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

> Given a metric space $(S,d)$ and a subset $T$ of $S$. If a point $p$ in $S$ is an adherent point of $T$, then there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $T$ which converges to $p$.

Here’s my proof:

$\implies$ If every $(x_n)$ does not converge to $p$, then $p$ does not adhere to the union of ranges of all such convergent sequences $(x_n)$ in $T$. Clearly, this union is $T$.

$\implies$ But by assumption, $p$ is adherent to $T$, a contradiction.

Is it correct?

Comment: Show that $p$ is adherent point of $T$ if and only if $p$ is in the closure of $T$. I don't know about your text specifically, but some texts show that $p$ is in the closure if and only if there is a sequence in $T$ that converges to $p$